# Powershell Close Form Null Expression

Tags: powershell, null

I'm certain I'm missing something stupid, but I can't get this figured. I have a script that creates a "Please Wait" popup while the code is running. The issue is that I can't get the popup to close after the script is done.

Here is how the popup gets called:

```
Function CheckShuffle()
{
    #Check Selection
        If ($Global:x -eq "" -or $Global:x -eq '0')
        {
            if ( $null -eq ('System.Windows.MessageBox' -as [type]) ) 
            {
                Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
            }
            [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('You must select your part first', 'Warning', 'OK')
        }
        Else
        {
        OpenSplash
        #Shuffle
        CloseSplash
        }
}
```

Here is the code for the popup:

```
Function OpenSplash()
{
$Splash = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Splash.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$Splash.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,200)


$SplashLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Splash.Controls.Add($SplashLabel)

$SplashLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(100,60)
$SplashLabel.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Microsoft Sans Serif", 16, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$SplashLabel.Text = "Please Wait"
$SplashLabel.AutoSize = $True
$Splash.Visible = $True
$Splash.Update()
}
```

I've tried a few ways to close it:

```
Function CloseSplash()
{
$This.Parent.Close()
}
```

This one one closes the primary form, not the splash screen.

```
Function CloseSplash()
{
$Splash.Close()
}
```

That one throws an error: "You cannot call a method on a null valued expression"

It looks like Powershell is forgetting what $Splash is, but I cannot figure out how to tell it.

Thank you all!

Edit: Worth noting, if I put the code all together instead of calling it, the popup closes as intended.

Comment: Your variable is [out of scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes). Make `OpenSplash` return the form, store it in a variable in `CheckShuffle`, and pass it to `CloseSplash` as an argument (or just put the `Close` directly in `CheckShuffle`, it's not worth its own function). For non-trivial code, consider using `Set-StrictMode`, as it gives you clear errors on trying to refer to non-existent variables or properties instead of silently returning defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeroen answered the question in a comment, and I don't see how to mark that as the answer, so I'm reposting here!

The solution:

I needed to make $splash global. This was super easy, I just had to make it say:

```
$Global:Splash
```

Thanks again Jeroen!